# how do i use httpclient to login in a website and perform some searching operation?

Tags: java, httpclient

i want to login into an web-application and want to perform some search operation after login. I am using httpclient for this and i am able to login and fetching the data of that page but i didn't get anyway to perform post operation say searching of any user account after login. As it is asking for login again. Please provide any way or idea to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you login into a site the server usually sends you back a cookie containing your session id, or the jsessionid header. Try sending this jsessionid and its value back to the server in the post-login operation.

This may not work, because the server can force you to use cookies. This is just an idea of the scenario often found around there.

Comment: thanks i m using jsesson-id for doing this bec'z i m getting it as a cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

Its not httpclient, but there is a browser automatization framework called [selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/).

Comment: ya i know this but we want pure java code not api dependent like selenium, httpUnit etc.

Answer (score 0):

look here for an explanation how to use cookies in java, using the java.net APIs http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html

Answer (score 0):

I have had a scoping issue with a session cookie not being visible in the past. You "may" have the same issue.If you know the session cookie is being created after you have logged in successfully, try adding a call to `setDomainMatchingStrict(false)`

```
import com.meterware.httpunit.cookies.CookieProperties;

WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();

CookieProperties.setDomainMatchingStrict(false);   // <- the important bit
```